# 3 dots in the end of TextView are vertically centered

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout, android-fragments

When using **android:ellipsize="end"** property, 3 dots are vertically centered instead of appearing in the bottom of the view.

How should I make 3 dots appear in the bottom?

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/widgetTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="@string/lorem_ipsum_short"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_4"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/spacing_2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/widgetTimeArrived"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        />
```

[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUEHF.png)

Comment: Hello VladD, welcome to SO. Please add the parent layout (is this TextView contained in the root ConstraintLayout? what is widgetTimeArrived?

Comment: Are you also using a custom font? I have created a normal ConstraintLayout + TextView and I don't see the same issue.

Comment: there is a problem with string I added direct text `Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit` and its ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell without access to your full layout, but that's not the standard behavior, so you may be using a custom Font/Theme.

This is how it looks in a blank layout with a ConstraintLayout:

[image: TextView with IDE/XML code and preview visible on the right]

Notice I pinned the "end" to the parent, since I don't know what your `widgetTimeArrived` is.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using custom font. (mplus_2c https://fonts2u.com/m-2c-black.font)
But when there are '...' in the text, dots are aligned properly. Only when using ellipsize property dots are aligned to the bottom.

Comment: Ellipses is a single character which may look different than three period characters in a row, depending on the font.

Comment: Thanks, Martin. I didn't know, that ellipsis is a separate symbol in Unicode system.
So it is custom font issue, not XML layout.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting your expected results by implementing your code. I think @Martin Marconcini is right about some custom theme or it might be some views alignment or constraint issue.Your full xml might be helpful to understand that.

Here are the results:

[image]